# why DatePicker Control showing error in Expression Blend for wp7 application?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, datepicker, expression-blend

I have developed window phone 7 application in visual studio 2010. In that application I have used the datepicker control from the following link

http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2010/09/19/using-the-datepicker-control-in-wp7.aspx

My project is running fine without any difficulty during the build operation as well as run operation in visual studio 2010. Now I have opened the same project in Expression blend. When I build the project in Expression Blend I get the error. The error is XamlParseException: [Line: 0 Position: 0]. But when I run the project in Expression Blend the project runs properly without any problem & all the functions work properly. The problem is only with build operation in Expression Blend. Can you please tell me why this is happening ? Can you please provide me any solution or link through which I can resolve the above issue which occurs during build operation ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend posting this on the Microsoft forums or on Connect (vs prod/wpd tooling) if you don't get a resolution here. It's potentially a bug.. they may or not be tracking it yet.